# One way binding of a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an image whose source is dynamically set using AngularJS like so:

```
ng-src="{{showEmbellishment(image.attrib)}}"
```

This will take the attrib of the image and show appropriate embellishment (the embellishment is an image). This works fine without any issues.

I now have a bunch of key press events tied to this page using Angular HotKeys:

```
hotkeys.add({
    combo: 'd',
    description: 'Do something',
    callback: function(event, hotkey) {
        //perform some action
    }
});
```

My problem is that when I press the 'd' key that added as a hotkey, for example, then it does perform what it is asked to, however I notice that the `showEmbellishment()` is once again called for all the images again. This is an overhead and is making the `d` key press action to become slower to complete.

I read on one-way binding but I am not sure how to implement it such that the `showEmbellishment()` is not needlessly called every time an unrelated action key is pressed.

Any pointers on solving this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[One-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) can work well in this case:

```
ng-src="{{:: showEmbellishment(image.attrib) }}"
```

Comment: I tried that, however the showEmbellishment still gets called when I press the 'd' button...

Comment: Hm, strange. It can't happen actually. Can you create a demo? http://plnkr.co/edit/ydEl27uRAqnuSiWlGiyW?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Angular needs to dirty check bound values on digest. And when you interact with the view, whether with key pressed, click or some input, digest is triggered. In case function is bound, the framework cannot know if the value has changed or not, without evaluating/calling the function. That's why that function will be called over and over (at least in angular 1.x), so you should keep that in mind for performance.

Here are two ideas how you can work around the issue:

- bind `ng-src` to a variable defined on the scope and change the value of it in the hotkey's callback.
- go with a custom directive approach, similar to [this one](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11416#issuecomment-94818097).